# Argument of type 'IContact[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FetchContactsSuccessPayload'

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

I am working on my own exercise with react redux-saga with TypsScript and I got stuck on a type inside my saga file. It is my first touch of ts.

My error is pointing to `saga.ts` file where code:

```
yield put(fetchContactsSuccess(data)).
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'IContact[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FetchContactsSuccessPayload'.

Property 'contacts' is missing in type 'IContact[]' but required in type 'FetchContactsSuccessPayload'.
```

Not sure what I am missing or messing.

types.ts

```
export interface FetchContactsSuccessPayload {
    contacts: IContact[]
}

export type FetchContactsRequest = {
    type: typeof GET_ALL_CONTACTS_REQUEST
}

export type FetchContactsSuccess = {
    type: typeof GET_ALL_CONTACTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: FetchContactsSuccessPayload
}

export type FetchContactsError = {
    type: typeof GET_ALL_CONTACTS_ERROR,
    payload: {message: string}
}
```

actions.ts

```
export const fetchContactsRequest = (): FetchContactsRequest => ({
    type: GET_ALL_CONTACTS_REQUEST,
})

export const fetchContactsSuccess = (payload: FetchContactsSuccessPayload): FetchContactsSuccess => ({
    type: GET_ALL_CONTACTS_SUCCESS,
    payload
})

export const fetchContactsError = (error: any) => ({
    type: GET_ALL_CONTACTS_ERROR,
    error
})
```

reducers.ts

```
export const contactReducer = (state=initialState, action: ProjectActionTypes) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ALL_CONTACTS_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: true,
            };
        case GET_ALL_CONTACTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                contacts: action.payload
            }
        case GET_ALL_CONTACTS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                error: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

saga.ts

```
export function* fetchContacts() {
    try {
        const data: IContact[]  = yield call(getContacts)
        console.log(data);
        
       yield put(fetchContactsSuccess(data))
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
}

export function* fetchAllContactsSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(GET_ALL_CONTACTS_REQUEST, fetchContacts)
}


export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([fork(fetchAllContactsSaga)])
}
```

I tried to use type any instead `IContact[]` but the response was still giving me the same error.

When I `console.log` the response I am getting a 200 status which means it is working and inside my logger, `GET_ALL_CONTACTS_REQUEST` is never triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface FetchContactsSuccessPayload {
    contacts: IContact[]
}
```

Your `FetchContactsSuccessPayload` is an *object* with a *property* `contacts` that contains the array of contacts.  This payload is the expected argument of your `fetchContactsSuccess` action creator.  But you are calling `fetchContactsSuccess(data)` with the array of contacts.

#### Solution 1: Change your saga

Pass a payload object instead of an array.

```
const data: IContact[]  = yield call(getContacts)
yield put(fetchContactsSuccess({ contacts: data }))
```

#### Solution 2: Change your action creator

Accept an array instead of a payload object.

```
export const fetchContactsSuccess = (contacts: IContact[]): FetchContactsSuccess => ({
    type: GET_ALL_CONTACTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: { contacts }
})
```